# How can I convert and round-up seconds to the next full minute?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a time usage amount in an Oracle table stored as a number of seconds:

```
5
10
100
500
```

How can I convert the number of seconds to the number of minutes, rounded up to the next closest minute? For the seconds values above I want to get:

```
1
1
2
9
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are actually using Oracle, you can use [the `CEIL` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions017.htm) to 'round up' the fractional number of minutes you get by dividing by 60 to the next integer.

```
ceil(your_column/60)
```

So with some sample values:

```
select seconds, ceil(seconds/60) as minutes
from your_table
order by seconds;

   SECONDS    MINUTES
---------- ----------
         5          1 
        10          1 
       100          2 
       500          9 
      1800         30
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to divide it by 60 and "trunc up". Unfortunately there isn't a built-in function that does exactly that, but [`trunc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm) can still be used:

```
SELECT CASE TRUNC(myseconds/60) WHEN myseconds/60 THEN myseconds/60
                                ELSE TRUNC(myseconds/60) + 1 
       END
FROM   my_table
```

EDIT:
Or in a more elegant form with a subquery:

```
SELECT CASE TRUNC(myminutes) WHEN myminutes THEN myminutes
                             ELSE TRUNC(myminutes) + 1 
           END
FROM   (SELECT myseconds/60 AS myminutes
        FROM   myable)
```

Comment: Thanx I will try, But I think we don't want use trunc, because this is a simple value like as a 5,10,100 and 500 and all are integer and I want result as a integer

Comment: If you divide two integers (e.g. 5 seconds by 60 to get a number of minutes), the result needn't be an integer - that's why `trunc` is used to convert it to an integer.